# Spotify API result limited to 2000?

Tags: python, api, limit, spotify, spotipy

I was trying to pull all the albums released every year from the Spotify catalogue through their API (using spotipy for python) but I stumbled into a limit of 2000 albums per year (the `offset` parameter seems to be capped at 2000), over which I get a 404 response.

Could someone clarify if this is a hard limit or if there is a workaround to get more than 2000 albums through their `search` endpoint?

There is no mention to this 2000 limit in the documentation of the Spotify API and would be a pity if we can only access such a limited amount of information (they don't even seem to offer a paid plan wihtout limit).
I found this [related issue](https://github.com/spotify/web-api/issues/862) but the workarounds listed there (adding `AND [a-z]*` for instance) seem not to work anymore.

EDIT:
Looks like the beta version of the docs include a reference to this limit for the `offset` parameter:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to get all the Albums per chunk.

So, on the first request, you'll get the first 2000 items;

```py
search('query', 2000, 0)
```

Then, on the second request, you'll need an [`offset`](https://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/2.16.1/#spotipy.client.Spotify.search) to tell spotify to 'skip' the first 2000 items;

```py
search('query', 2000, 2000)
```

Then, you can keep sending these requests until you have each available album;

```
search('query', 2000, 4000)
```

[Spotipy documentation](https://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/2.16.1/#spotipy.client.Spotify.search):
[image]

Comment: This is what I am doing at the moment. Unfortunately it looks like there is a maximum for the `offset` parameter which is set to 2000 which is only mentioned in the beta documentation, I just found it. https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference-beta/#category-browse if you scroll to the `search` endpoint you will see that offset is capped to 2000...any idea to get more than 2000 results from the `search` endpoint?or an alternative approach for getting all the albums released in a given year?

Comment: You should clarify that in the question, and/or show some code. I'm not able to find anything related to the 2000 max on the `offset`, also not in de link you provided.

Comment: Clarified the question. This is what I see when I click on the `Search API` in the left panel of the page I linked in my previous comment under the `offset` parameter:

offset
The index of the first result to return.
Default: 0 (the first result).
Maximum offset (including limit): 2,000.
Use with limit to get the next page of search results.