# How do I scrape all spotify playlists ever?

Tags: web-scraping, spotify, playlist

I am trying to analyze all user-curated Spotify playlists and the tracks inside all of them, especially in the hip-hop genre. The result that I want is **a list of user-curated playlists ID (preferably 50,000 playlist IDs)**

I have tried using [`search API`](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/#/operations/search) and [Get Category’s Playlist Spotify API](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/#/operations/get-a-categories-playlists).
The problem is that

1. There is a 1,000 data limit for[`search API`](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/#/operations/search).
2. [Get Category’s Playlist Spotify API](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/#/operations/get-a-categories-playlists) only gives out Spotify-curated playlists on each genre.

I also tried to go around the [`search API`](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/#/operations/search) by thinking of parsing different queries (i.e. search on 'a','b','c','d',...). However, I still have no idea which queries will best represent Spotify playlists as a whole (as searching 'a','b',... would be considered too random). I would appreciate any help or ideas!

This is what I have tried with [Get Category’s Playlist Spotify API](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/#/operations/get-a-categories-playlists) with Spotipy Library in Google Colab

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import spotipy
import spotipy.util as util
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyClientCredentials
import spotipy.oauth2 as oauth2

# Replace Auth details with your Client ID, Secret
spotify_details = {
    'client_id' : 'Client ID',
    'client_secret':'Client Secret',
    'redirect_uri':'Redirect_uri'}

scope = "user-library-read user-follow-read user-top-read playlist-read-private playlist-read-collaborative playlist-modify-public playlist-modify-private" 

sp = spotipy.Spotify(
        auth_manager=spotipy.SpotifyOAuth(
          client_id=spotify_details['client_id'],
          client_secret=spotify_details['client_secret'],
          redirect_uri=spotify_details['redirect_uri'],    
          scope=scope,open_browser=False))


results = sp.category_playlists(category_id="hiphop", limit = 5, country="US", offset=0)
total = results["playlists"]["total"]
df=pd.DataFrame([],columns = ['id', 'name', 'external_urls.spotify'])
for offset in range(0,total,50):
  results = sp.category_playlists(category_id="hiphop", limit = 50, country="US", offset=offset)
  playlists = pd.json_normalize(results['playlists']['items'])
  #print(playlists.keys)
  df=pd.concat([df,playlists])
df
```

I only can get around 104 playlists when I run

```py
print(len(df)) 
>>104
```

P.S. This number varies around 80-100+ depending on the location of your account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Main idea is same as @Nima Akbarzadeh's idea with `offset`

I am using `axios` call with Spotify API call on node.js

Got the playlists first, then get track within loop each playlist.

This Code can get all of `hiphop` songs from Spotify.

```js
const axios = require('axios')

const API_KEY='<your client ID>'
const API_KEY_SECRET='<your client Secret>'

const getToken = async () => {
    try {
        const resp = await axios.post(
            url = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
            data = '',
            config = {
                params: {
                    'grant_type': 'client_credentials'
                },
                auth: {
                    username: API_KEY,
                    password: API_KEY_SECRET
                }
            }
        );
        return Promise.resolve(resp.data.access_token);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
        return Promise.reject(err)
    }
};
const getCategories = async (category_id, token) => {
    try {
        let offset = 0
        let next = 1
        const songs = [];
        while (next != null) {
            const resp = await axios.get(
                url = `https://api.spotify.com/v1/browse/categories/${category_id}/playlists?country=US&offset=${offset}&limit=20`,
                config = {
                    headers: {
                        'Accept-Encoding': 'application/json',
                        'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
                    }
                }
            );
            
            for(const item of resp.data.playlists.items) {
                if(item?.name != null) {
                    songs.push({
                        name: item.name,
                        external_urls: item.external_urls.spotify,
                        type: item.type,
                        id : item.id
                    })
                }
            }

            offset = offset + 20

            next = resp.data.playlists.next
        }
        return Promise.resolve(songs)
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
        return Promise.reject(err)
    }
}

const getTracks = async (playlists, token) => {
    try {
        const tracks = [];
        for(const playlist of playlists) {
            const resp = await axios.get(
                url = `https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/${playlist.id}`,
                config = {
                    headers: {
                        'Accept-Encoding': 'application/json',
                        'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
                    }
                }
            );
            for(const item of resp.data.tracks.items) {
                if(item.track?.name != null) {
                    tracks.push({
                        name: item.track.name,
                        external_urls: item.track.external_urls.spotify
                    })
                }
            }
        }
        return Promise.resolve(tracks)
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
        return Promise.reject(err)
    }
};

getToken()
    .then(token => {
        getCategories('hiphop', token)
            .then(playlists => {
                getTracks(playlists, token)
                    .then(tracks => {
                        for(const track of tracks) {
                            console.log(track)
                        }
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.log(error.message);
                    });  
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error.message);
            });
      
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error.message);
    });
```

I got 6435 songs

```
$ node get-data.js
[
  {
    name: 'RapCaviar',
    external_urls: 'https://open.spotify.com/playlist/37i9dQZF1DX0XUsuxWHRQd',
    type: 'playlist',
    id: '37i9dQZF1DX0XUsuxWHRQd'
  },
  {
    name: "Feelin' Myself",
    external_urls: 'https://open.spotify.com/playlist/37i9dQZF1DX6GwdWRQMQpq',
    type: 'playlist',
    id: '37i9dQZF1DX6GwdWRQMQpq'
  },
  {
    name: 'Most Necessary',
    external_urls: 'https://open.spotify.com/playlist/37i9dQZF1DX2RxBh64BHjQ',
    type: 'playlist',
    id: '37i9dQZF1DX2RxBh64BHjQ'
  },
  {
    name: 'Gold School',
    external_urls: 'https://open.spotify.com/playlist/37i9dQZF1DWVA1Gq4XHa6U',
    type: 'playlist',
    id: '37i9dQZF1DWVA1Gq4XHa6U'
  },
  {
    name: 'Locked In',
    external_urls: 'https://open.spotify.com/playlist/37i9dQZF1DWTl4y3vgJOXW',
    type: 'playlist',
    id: '37i9dQZF1DWTl4y3vgJOXW'
  },
  {
    name: 'Taste',
    external_urls: 'https://open.spotify.com/playlist/37i9dQZF1DWSUur0QPPsOn',
    type: 'playlist',
    id: '37i9dQZF1DWSUur0QPPsOn'
  },
  {
    name: 'Get Turnt',
    external_urls: 'https://open.spotify.com/playlist/37i9dQZF1DWY4xHQp97fN6',
    type: 'playlist',
    id: '37i9dQZF1DWY4xHQp97fN6'
  },
...
 {
    name: 'BILLS PAID (feat. Latto & City Girls)',
    external_urls: 'https://open.spotify.com/track/0JiLQRLOeWQdPC9rVpOqqo'
  },
  {
    name: 'Persuasive (with SZA)',
    external_urls: 'https://open.spotify.com/track/67v2UHujFruxWrDmjPYxD6'
  },
  {
    name: 'Shirt',
    external_urls: 'https://open.spotify.com/track/34ZAzO78a5DAVNrYIGWcPm'
  },
  {
    name: 'Back 2 the Streets',
    external_urls: 'https://open.spotify.com/track/3Z9aukqdW2HuzFF1x9lKUm'
  },
  {
    name: 'FTCU (feat. GloRilla & Gangsta Boo)',
    external_urls: 'https://open.spotify.com/track/4lxTmHPgoRWwM9QisWobJL'
  },
  {
    name: 'My Way',
    external_urls: 'https://open.spotify.com/track/5BcIBbBdkjSYnf5jNlLG7j'
  },
  {
    name: 'Donk',
    external_urls: 'https://open.spotify.com/track/58lmOL5ql1YIXrpRpoYi3i'
  },
  ... 6335 more items
]
```

```
node get-data.js > result.json
```

[image]

#### Update with Python version

```py
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyOAuth
import json
import re

SCOPE = ['user-library-read',
    'user-follow-read',
    'user-top-read',
    'playlist-read-private',
    'playlist-read-collaborative',
    'playlist-modify-public',
    'playlist-modify-private']
USER_ID = '<your user id>'
REDIRECT_URI = '<your redirect uri>'
CLIENT_ID = '<your client id>'
CLIENT_SECRET = '<your client secret>'
auth_manager = SpotifyOAuth(
    scope=SCOPE,
    username=USER_ID,
    redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI,
    client_id=CLIENT_ID,
    client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET)

def get_categories():
    try:
        sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=auth_manager)
        query_limit = 50
        categories=[]
        new_offset = 0
        while True:
            results=sp.category_playlists(category_id='hiphop', limit = query_limit, country='US', offset=new_offset)
            for item in results['playlists']['items']:
                if (item is not None and item['name'] is not None):
                    # ['https:', '', 'api.spotify.com', 'v1', 'playlists', '37i9dQZF1DX0XUsuxWHRQd', 'tracks']
                    tokens = re.split(r"[\/]", item['tracks']['href'])
                    categories.append({
                        'id' : item['id'],
                        'name': item['name'],
                        'url': item['external_urls']['spotify'],
                        'tracks': item['tracks']['href'],
                        'playlist_id': tokens[5],
                        'type': item['type']
                    })
            new_offset = new_offset + query_limit
            next = results['playlists']['next']
            if next is None:
                break
        return categories
    except Exception as e:
        print('Failed to upload to call get_categories: '+ str(e))

def get_songs(categories):
    try:
        sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=auth_manager)
        songs=[]
        for category in categories:
            if category is None:
                break
            playlist_id = category['playlist_id']
            results=sp.playlist(playlist_id=playlist_id)
            for item in results['tracks']['items']:
                if (item is not None and item['track'] is not None and item['track']['id'] is not None and item['track']['name'] is not None and item['track']['external_urls']['spotify'] is not None):
                    songs.append({
                        'id' : item['track']['id'],
                        'name': item['track']['name'],
                        'url': item['track']['external_urls']['spotify']
                    })
                else:
                    break
        return songs
    except Exception as e:
        print('Failed to upload to call get_songs: '+ str(e))

categories = get_categories()
songs = get_songs(categories)
print(json.dumps(songs))
# print(len(songs)) -> 6021
```

Result by

```
$ python get-songs.py > all-songs.json
```

[image]

Comment: Great example. Thank you for completing my answer.

Comment: No problem! we are learn from each other.

Comment: Thank you so much for the clear explanation and code. I have tried something similar and can only get around 100 spotify-curated playlists. Is there away to also get user-curated playlists data too?

Comment: @TanachaiA, can you show reprodurable code for `only get around 100 spotify-curated playlists.`? I need to run it in my hand thenI can figure out what is your talking about.

Comment: @BenchVue I have added more details on the similar code that you shared on python. If you have any problem with the code, please let me know. Thank you so much!

Comment: @TanachaiA, I added a python code and result, I got 6021 songs.

Comment: @BenchVue May I ask how many playlists did you get? I guess you scraped 6021 songs from scraping a number of playlists.

Comment: @BenchVue I can only get around 104 playlists.

Comment: @TanachaiA, I got from the get_categories() is 117 categories, I got from get_songs() is 6021 songs.

Comment: Thank you for trying the same code. Do you know how to get more playlists than that? It doesn't need to be in the Hip Hop category but they needed to be user-curated playlists, not Spotify-curated playlists that are created by Spotify?

Comment: Which category can makes it? `hiphop` is not good example.

Comment: I checked all of genres of Spotify (53 genres), the highest categories(playlist) total is `K-Pop`. It's number is 212, second is `Latin`. It's number is 199. None of them not over 1000 playlists.

Comment: Can you tell me what is the number of total playlists that you scraped from all genres?

Comment: This [API](https://developer.spotify.com/console/get-browse-categories/) can get all genres and It returned category name and if, it  can call get [single category's playlist](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/#/operations/get-a-categories-playlists)(genre) API for each  genre. It can count a total number for each genre.

Comment: @TanachaiA, Is it time to vote me?

Comment: Thank you for your ideas and contribution. I saved and accepted the answer @bench

Comment: @TanachaiA, Thanks for your cooperation, I also learn a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Spotify will not let you scrape more than 1K as their application even show maximum 1k music (based on [this](https://community.spotify.com/t5/Desktop-Windows/Search-Results-Limitation-1-000/td-p/5240990) answer).

Also, if there is any **offset** option, you can set it to 1k, and it will skip the first 1k, so you can get the second chunk.

Comment: @Ximzend I worked with it in the past and was fine. You can also check it here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64810063/spotify-api-result-limited-to-2000

Comment: They changed it from 2000 to 1000 somewhere in between [February 06 2021](https://web.archive.org/web/20210206145717/https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/) and [February 09 2021](https://web.archive.org/web/20210209170649/https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/).

Comment: @Ximzend Check out the new answer.

Comment: I thought you were talking about the search offset, but the offset for playlist tracks can indeed go beyond 1000 tracks.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I think the offset of search API cannot go beyond 1000 which means I cannot get over 1000 playlists per search query. But there are no such limit when getting tracks from a playlist. Is this correct?